# Get web page content where source code isn't visible

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to get all the Advisory ID and CVE ID from this page  https://psirt.global.sonicwall.com/vuln-list

My earlier approach was to extract links and IDs from source code (I have followed this approach with other vendors such as Google chrome update and Mozilla update). But here I cannot see any data in the source code. When I am in inspect mode though, I can see the data. However, when I view the source code, I cannot find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried logging the traffic and then searching for the piece of data it seems like it's requesting `https://psirtapi.global.sonicwall.com/api/v1/vulnsummary/?srch=&vulnerable_products=&ord=-advisory_id` for the data, you're looking for and then returns it in the response. You can then parse it.

[image: The arrow point is what you're looking for]